# Flex Component Libraries?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I've been asked by my boss to make a semi-functional mockup of a webapp using flex.  He has requested that it looks as "WOW!" as possible. The built in flex components are pretty basic.  Are there any libraries out there with nifty looking components?  The only one I have found is flexlib, which is awesome, but I still need more components. I'd also like to find some nice looking charts as well.

p.s. My boss is one of those "OOH IT'S SHINY!" kind of guys, so the more unnecessary bells and whistles the better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the [Tour De Flex](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex/).  It includes a section with 3rd party libraries with demos.

Here's a [list of components, libraries, and APIs](http://seantheflexguy.com/blog/2007/08/21/list-of-31-flex-apis-libraries-components-and-tools/).

For styling an application, start off with the [Flex Style Explorer](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/samples/style_explorer/).

Answer (score 2):

There's [ILOG Elixir](http://www.ilog.com/products/ilogelixir/), but it's not free. We used it at my last job; it's pretty nice.

Also, be careful, when your boss says to show him something shiny quickly.  You may be asked to develop a system in less time than is physically possible.

Comment: oh wow, those look really nice.

And don't worry, I've already been asked to develop lots of things in a short amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need more components, or do you need a better look for the ones in there?  Check out scalenine for a whole bunch of Flex based styles, some of which definately have an "oh wow" look.

http://scalenine.com/

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually using one of the styles from there already

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at http://lab.kapit.fr/

There are a lot of free chart components there that may impress your boss.

Answer (score 1):

This website has a list of Flex components:

http://seantheflexguy.com/blog/2008/05/24/36-new-cool-flex-and-as3-tools-libraries-and-components/

Or check this link:

http://fleksray.org/adobe_flex_components_en.html

Or this:

http://www.afcomponents.com/components/